# Multi-columnar legend in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, charts

Instead of having legend scroll, I want to make it multi-columnar. I will fix the height of legend, and if the items exceed the legend, then it should extend one more column to display extra legend and so on.
Is this possible in flex. Any help idea is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, but I think you'd need to create a custom component to do that. A starting point would be the Flex SDK implementation, but it's likely going to be overkill, and you're probably better off building your own.